# QImage does not load image even when it exists

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

```
def setPixData(self,data):
    print(data) #this print the image file name correctly e.g asdfghj.jpg
    img=QtGui.QImage(QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath ()+"/temp/"+data)
    pix=QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
    self.driver_ui.pix.setPixmap(pix)
```

This loads the image correctly when I run it from the development code.
Once I freeze it with cx_freeze and install it in final destination directory, it does not load the image. Even though the image is in the specified path.

I have tried hardcoding the full path into the frozen version, still no luck.
I've placed a `f.write()` at every other line of the above code, and they all ran with no error.
I figured the problem is from `QImage` since it returns true on `isNull()`

What could be the problem, If `QImage` is not being added by cx_freeze, it will sure throw and exception and wont run the `f.write()` on next line.
I am lost here.

NOTE: it's a windows GUI app in python.

Comment: Please, always use `os.path.join()` to construct paths; `os.path.join(QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath(), 'temp', data)` in your case. Not sure if that'll solve your issue, but it can avoid a host of problems on Windows with mixed delimiters, for example.

Comment: Thanks, i just implemented that but no luck still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `Qt uses "/" as a universal directory separator in the same way that "/" is used as a path separator in URLs. If you always use "/" as a directory separator, Qt will translate your paths to conform to the underlying operating system.` http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdir.html

Comment: @Slavik81: Interesting. In that case `os.path.join` will do the right thing anyway as presumably `QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath()` will use `/` as the separator.

Comment: I didn't use `cx_freeze` but this is usually the case when a 'freezer' doesn't pack all the necessary files. In this case image plugins. They are usually in PyQt installation folder under `plugins/imageformats`. Alternatively, you can try [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It usually does the right thing with PyQt apps.

Comment: Did you try to see if `QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath() + '/temp/' + data` actually exists? I mean, calling `os.path.exists` on it or something like that?

Comment: Thanks Avaris, I copied the imageformats folder along with my app and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely giving it an incorrect file path. The fact that the file exists *somewhere* doesn't help QImage, if you don't give it a correct file path.

Comment: Problem solved! I copied the plugins/imageformats folder located in the plugins directory of my PyQt installation folder to my application folder Thanks Avaris and other for contributions